# How do I download/set values dynamically from API in TypeScript(Angular 4)?

Tags: angular, api, typescript

I'm making a TFS manager app using Angular 4, which should display projects and their build definitions.

I've got a definitions[] that I display in a list. Next to each definition, I'm supposed to show the result of the last build. Problem is, to show result of the last build I need to get all builds for each definition displayed, which in some of my projects means over 500 API requests. It takes over half a minute, and you can't see the definition until it's build result is ready.

What i want to achieve is to display the definitions and display the build results why they're there - preferably one by one, but if all would be displayed when the last one is ready would be a huge improvement aswell.

Here's my code:

```
//api request for definitions
getBuildDefinitions(): void {
  this.http.get('http://localhost:54639/api/tfs/builddefinitions?id=' +
  this.currentProject.id).subscribe(data => {
    this.definitions = data['value'];
  })
}

//definitions declaration and setter
_definitions: Definition[];
set definitions(definitions: Definition[]) {
  this._definitions = definitions;
  this.getBuilds();
}

//get builds for all definitions
getBuilds() {
  for (let d of this._definitions) {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:54639/api/tfs/builds?projectId=' + 
    this.currentProject.id + '&definitionId=' + d.id).subscribe(data => {
      d.builds = data['value'];
    })
  }
}

//declaration of component in the main app - all the above code       
<app-definitions-list [definitions]="_definitions 
(currentDefinition)="getSelectedDefinition($event)"></app-definitions-list>

//here's how I want to display them
<button *ngFor="let d of currentDefinitions" 
(click)='onDefinitionSelected(d)'>{{ d.builds[0].result }} {{ d.name }}
</button>
```

My guess would be that I need to make a hard copy of _definitions before I get the builds and then set _definitions to the copy with builds. However, a) how do you make a hard copy in typescript? and b) how do I await for the api request to finnish before setting _definitions back to the temporary copy? HttpClient requests are async and require me to subscribe to them, I've gotta admit I don't quite grasp the concept.

Or maybe there is a way to display result of build one by one instead of all at once when they're downloaded?

Edit: found out the solution 3secs after posting this. I did it like that:

```
<div *ngIf="d.builds">{{ d.builds[0].result }}</div> {{ d.name }}
```

Now it dynamically displays results.

Answer (score 1):

at first you can create a hardcopy using slice() method.

```
let hardCopyArray = originalArray.slice();
```

in order to wait for all response to come back you can do this:

```
getBuilds() {
  // the number of requests = the length of the array;
  let requestCount = this._definitions.length;
  for (let d of this._definitions) {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:54639/api/tfs/builds?projectId=' + 
    this.currentProject.id + '&definitionId=' + d.id).subscribe(data => {
      d.builds = data['value'];
      // each response came, decrement the requestCount
      requestCount--;
      // then check if this is the last response;
      this.isAllResponseBack(requestCount);
    })
  }
}

isAllResponseBack(requestCount : number ) {
   if(requestCount == 0) {
      console.log('this is the last response');
   }else{
      console.log('not the last response');
   }
}
```